# Column null in database

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to know how can I save the id of the post in my table `post_tag`, column `post_id`?Now, when I add a new post, in my table is saved only `tag_id`, can you give me some help with that?I'm watching a tutorial but I'm stuck with this problem.Thank you.

**create_post_tag_table**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePostTagTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('post_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('post_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('post_id')->references('id')->on('posts');

            $table->integer('tag_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('tag_id')->references('id')->on('tags');

        });
    }

}
```

**PostsController with function store**

```
 public function store(Request $request )
    {



        $data = request()->validate([

            'caption' => 'required|max:255',
            'image' => 'required|image',
        ]);
        $post = new Post;

        $post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);



        $imagePath = request('image')->store('uploads', 'public');

        $image = Image::make(public_path("storage/{$imagePath}"))->fit(1600, 1100);
        $image->save();

        auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'caption' => $data['caption'],
            'image' => $imagePath,
        ]);



         return redirect('/profile/' . auth()->user()->id);
    }
```

**create_tags_table**

```
  public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**create_posts_table**

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('caption');
            $table->string('image');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->index('user_id');
        });
    }
```

Now, with this lines `$post = new Post;` and  `$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);` my tag id is saved in `tag_id` column, but my new post id from table `posts` isn't.How can I save my post id in my `post_id` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two different Post objects.

```
$post = new Post;

$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);

auth()->user()->posts()->create([ // this creates another one
    'caption' => $data['caption'],
    'image' => $imagePath,
]);
```

Withouth knowing to much about what you are trying to achieve. I think you can obtain your desired logic by instead of creating a new one, saving the one already existing to the user. (Usually i think $request->user() is a better aproach to getting the user out). You will also need to add, these fields to the first post object.

```
$post = new Post([
    'caption' => $data['caption'],
    'image' => $imagePath,
]);

//code in between should still be there

$request->user()->posts()->save($post);
```

Comment: This `$request->user()->posts()->save($post);` should be before  `auth()->user()->posts()->create` ?

Comment: Replace it, you are creating two posts, just updated the question, when you call that save method, it will automatic create/save the object

Answer (score 1):

The synchronisation between the post and tags is done when creating the model-object. At this point it is actually synchronising a model with ID null to an existing tag-id, resulting in the situation that post_id will be empty in the database.

By executing `$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);` after you saved the model it should work.

Comment: Thanks for answer.This should be after `auth()->user()->posts()->create` ?

Answer (score 1):

First create your post

```
$post = auth()->user()->posts()->create([
        'caption' => $data['caption'],
        'image' => $imagePath,
    ]);
```

Then assign tags

```
$post->tags()->sync($request->tags, false);
```

additionally you can try chaining the tags()->sync() with post()->create() method, but i haven't tested.

Answer (score 0):

Have tried using the OnUpdate and onDelete methods chained to your migration file?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understand what are you meaning...I'm kinda beginner at Laravel, maybe you can give me ab example to better understanding? Thanks